# Is the mapping $\phi(f,x) = f(x)$, where $x \in E$, and $f \in L(E)$ and $E$ is a vector space, a bilinear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, bilinear-form, dual-spaces

> Is the mapping $\phi(f,x) = f(x)$, where $x \in E$, and $f \in L(E)$
>   and $E$ is a vector space, a bilinear function ?

In the definition of the book I use, *Werner Greub Linear Algebra*, the codomain of a bilinear function has to be a field, but in this example since $f$ is a linear mapping on $E$, the images of $f$ are in $E$, which is not a field, so from this argument, $\phi$ cannot be a bilinear function but in the book page 66, it says that if is a bilinear mapping, so where is the problem in my argument ?

Comment: Not only a general theory of bilinear maps $f:V\times W\to H$, where $V,W,H$ are $\Bbb F$-vector spaces (or even $R$-modules) is possible, but it has actually been extensively developed. Perhaps the author of your book only wants to deal with scalar products, and he is thus interested mainly in the case $H=\Bbb F$ and $V=W$ (sometimes called "bilinear forms on $V$").

Comment: @Fakemistake if you check the book carefully, bilinear functions are given before the definition of dual spaces, so you cannot talk about dual spaces at this point because I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Fakemistake Its is not just related, it is **the** question that I'm asking.

Comment: @Fakemistake $f(x)$ cannot be a field element because $f$ itself is a linear transformation on $E$, so $f(x)$ has to be a vector in $E$.